# Can we have a [signal-processing] tag?

Tags: support, tags

[This question](http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/473/how-to-amplify-mans-voice-in-a-noisy-recording) was originally posted on StackOverflow, where it was suggested it belongs on audio.SE.  I don't see a [signal-processing] tag on audio.SE, and this is definitely a signal processing question.  Can someone with sufficient rep add this tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added.